# Rotate part of object

Tags: mesh

Anyone know how I can rotate or flip the wings down?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To rotate an object, press the key 'r', and then press either 'x', 'y', or 'z' to get the rotation in a specific axis (This is not required. You can press 'r' and rotate freely.). The rotation will be based on the origin of the object, or the tiny yellow dot that shows up when you select it. In your case, if the origin is not at the base of the wing, follow these steps:

1. 'Tab' to enter Edit Mode
2. Select the bottom face of the wing
3. Press 'Shift + S' and choose 'Cursor to selected'
4. Exit Edit Mode
5. Right click >> Set Origin >> Origin to 3D Cursor

Now, when you rotate in object mode, it should rotate and flip down.

Comment: Ok, but how would I remove the “clip” that keeps the wing up (in pic it’s like a curved line) and how would I make it look like it hasn’t been rotated and make it look seamless?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the foldable part of the wing a separate object and move its origin to a vertice on the edge of the wing (select the vertice and "Shift+S"> "Move 3d cursor to selected") .
Then you can put the 3d cursor on the  corresponding vertice on the first half of the wing. Now in object mode, moving the foldable part to the 3D cursor with "Shift+S" > "Move selection to 3d cursor" will exactly alling those two vertices and if you choose them well the whole wing will be alligned as well. Now you can join the objects again. You can now "Merge by distance" to get rid of the seam completely.

Comment: Now I have realized that you can just select the foldable part and turn on vertice snapping. Its the magnet symbol on the top of the viewport window and you have to open the dropdown menu and select vertice snapping. now you can move the wing with "g" and try to allign them. I think that the vertice closest to your cursor upon pressing g is the one it tries to snap to. This method usually takes a few tries because it can be a bit unpredictable tho.